# Can VideoView be implemented inside InfoWindow marker?

Tags: android-videoview, infowindow, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to add videoView inside a infoWindow,is it possible?Can anyone give me an example. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From GoogleMap Api Docs... An info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window. Sadly,it seems like it means no video on infowindow marker

hopefully someone prove me wrong